# how to check failure of a command in github action

Tags: github, github-actions, stm32

I integrate STM32CubeProgrammer with github action for deploy.

Although the command exit with error, github action workflow did not fail so that the result is success.

Because the command print "Error" at console log, I just want to grep this and make the workflow fail. how can I do that?

I am using self-hosted runner(Windows 10)

```
jobs:
  build:...
    
  deployment:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: [ self-hosted, deploy ]
    needs: build
    environment: production

    # Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
    steps:
      # Runs a set of commands using the runners shell
      - name: deploy
        run: |
          STM32_Programmer_CLI.exe -c port=SWD -w ${{ secrets.ELF_FILE }} ${{ secrets.START_ADDR }}
      
      - name: start
        run: |
          STM32_Programmer_CLI.exe -c port=SWD -c port=SWD -s ${{ secrets.START_ADDR }}
```

Comment: An option could be to extract the command line output inside a variable, and then check if the variable contains an ERROR message to force a failure or not (with `run: exit 1`).